# Flutter Agora Ui video disable by default

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I have a video channel code in which users can do video calls on a channel. What I need to do is when the user comes the first time then the video is turned off till the user wants to enable it. right now its default camera is on but I need to default off

```
class VideoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final roomid;
  const VideoPage({Key? key, this.roomid}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<VideoPage> createState() => _VideoPageState();
}

class _VideoPageState extends State<VideoPage> {
  bool videoIconEnable = false;
  bool enableVideo = false;

  final AgoraClient client = AgoraClient(
    agoraEventHandlers: (AgoraRtcEventHandlers(leaveChannel: (state) {
      Get.back();
    })),
    // videoDisabled: true,
    agoraConnectionData: AgoraConnectionData(
        appId: "e0700cba7e944848a29e****",
        channelName: "***",
        username: "asdrere",
        tempToken:
            "006e0700cba7****3d9b2IACy1MhejFRYOOqTS9FVTDH+2aMwmwVbbHjpVlqMbEY1ubd/Wk0AAAAAEACGukDPURzvYgEAAQBRHO9i"),
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initAgora();
  }

  void initAgora() async {
    await client.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    // client.leaveChannel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            // leading: GestureDetector(
            //   onTap: () {
            //     Get.back();
            //   },
            //   child: Icon(
            //     Icons.arrow_back_ios,
            //     color: Colors.grey,
            //   ),
            // ),
            actions: [
              videoIconEnable
                  ? GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () async {
                        setState(() {
                          enableVideo = true;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.video_call,
                          color: kPrimarycolor,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : Container()
            ],
            title: Text(
              'On Call',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: kPrimarycolor,
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              TweenAnimationBuilder<Duration>(
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
                  tween:
                      Tween(begin: Duration(seconds: 10), end: Duration.zero),
                  onEnd: () {
                    setState(() {
                      videoIconEnable = true;
                    });
                    print('Timer ended');
                  },
                  builder:
                      (BuildContext context, Duration value, Widget? child) {
                    final minutes = value.inMinutes;
                    final seconds = value.inSeconds % 60;
                    return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                        child: Text('Video will start in$minutes:$seconds',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 30)));
                  }),
              videoIconEnable
                  ? AgoraVideoViewer(
                      client: client,
                      layoutType: Layout.floating,
                      

                      enableHostControls:
                          true, // Add this to enable host controls
                    )
                  : Container(),
              AgoraVideoButtons(
                client: client,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

All buttons are working fine disable enable video but I need to default value of video false.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle video using agora ui kit.

```
await client.initialize();

client.sessionController.updateUserVideo(
   uid: client.agoraConnectionData.uid ?? 0,
   videoDisabled: !widget.videoEnabled);

 client.sessionController.value.copyWith(
     isLocalVideoDisabled:
         !(client.sessionController.value.isLocalVideoDisabled));
 await client.sessionController.value.engine?.muteLocalVideoStream(
     client.sessionController.value.isLocalVideoDisabled);
```